# How to install nltk_contrib in Anaconda

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, nltk

The google search for " how to install nltk_contrib" returns the [GITHub](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib) link as well as a link from [web.mit.edu](http://web.mit.edu/6.863/python/old/nltk-contrib-1.2/INSTALL.TXT). The second link mentions an installer for Windows which I could not find anywhere.
The instructions:

conda install nltk_contrib

pip install nltk_contrib

fail stating that no package found. The nltk.org doesn't even mention this module.
Could anyone provide me instructions for installing this module in Anaconda in Windows. Any instructions for installing from GitHub would also be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you'll have to set it up manually. Use `git` to download the entire hierarchy to your computer, move it to the `site-packages` of your python or add its location to your `PYTHONPATH`, and try it out. Be aware that this code base is not actively maintained -- it hasn't even been ported to Python 3 yet, so if you find something you can use, you'll need to port it yourself or use Python 2.

Anyway this is how you fetch it with git:

```
git clone https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib.git
```

Or go to https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib and use the <kbd>[Download ZIP](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib/archive/master.zip)</kbd> button to fetch the packages without their history.

Comment: Thank you alexis for your kind help :)