# nltk_contrib for python latest version (python version > 3)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk

I have installed python 3.5 and NLTK. Also, I have installed the `nltk_contrib` library from https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib which is not supporting to the latest version of python. The error is that the library written for older version. So, the library has `print` without parenthesis which will not support to the latest version of Python.

Is there any latest version `nltk_contrib` without down grade the python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of the useable code in `nltk_contrib` has been ported to `nltk`. I think `nltk_contrib` is no longer maintained.

Comment: @alvas. Thanks for the information. It would be helpful, if you provide any documentation for this.

Comment: check the dates of the last commits. It's usually a good indication of whether a repository is still maintained currently.

Comment: I checked that in python 3.5, it is not worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nltk contrib has not been ported to python 3 yet.

See this answer for more details:

[How to install nltk_contrib in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134730/how-to-install-nltk-contrib-in-anaconda)

You need to figure out which part of the code you need for python 3 and either port it yourself.

Or set up a virtualenv or and env for anaconda with python 2.7 and use it there.

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html

Comment: The most of NLTK library files are ported to Python 3. If I go with Python 2.7, the NLTK will support?

Comment: Thanks Vikash. The NLTK already I mapped with latest version and installed so many libraries to Python 3.5. Can I copy and paste those libraries to the older version or I have to Install from scratch? Please let me know

Comment: you will have to reinstall everything separately for 2.7 env as the library version you have installed for 3.5 might not be compatible with 2.7

Comment: OMG! reinstall again will take more time. I will port it to latest version. Tanks again Vikash.

Comment: you can use `conda list` command and get the list of libraries  that you have for that environment and do `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131717/discussion-between-nisar-and-vikash-singh).